# How to arrange multiple html elements based on x-y coordinates and width-height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am developing a digital signage application in HTML5 in which I will have a screen which will be playing/showing various medias setup by user.  I have multiple elements like video, images, widgets, ticker etc. I have x-y axis of elements and their height/width, I want to arrange them precisely based on the information given. I will get data in either xml/json.

I have tried with plain CSS, but it not working as expected. I tried SVG and Canvas, but they do not support all the html elemnts.

Comment: CSS `position:absolute;left:x;top:y;width:w;height:h` - of course, `x, y, w, h` are "variables" so don't take that CSS to be exactly what you'd use, you need to make the appropriate substitutions

Comment: How about a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply position elements using `absolute` from Javascript:

```
function absElement(type, x, y, w, h) {
    let d = document.createElement(type);
    d.style.position = "absolute";
    d.style.left = x + "px";
    d.style.top = y + "px";
    d.style.width = w + "px";
    d.style.height = h + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    return d;
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
absElement("img", 100, 200, 400, 200).src = "myimage.jpg";
```

Comment: If the set of ancestors are not positioned... otherwise `position:fixed` will be needed. (I know in your example you're appending to `body` but one may need to place it somewhere else in the tree)